# Create an ID to identify each loop in SAS

Tags: loops, sas

I have a log dataset in SAS like this, which has been ordered by TimeStamp ascendantly

```
TimeStamp           Status
2015Dec01:1:00:00   1
2015Dec01:2:00:00   2
2015Dec01:3:00:00   3
2015Dec01:4:00:00   4
2015Dec01:5:00:00   1
2015Dec01:6:00:00   2
2015Dec01:7:00:00   2
2015Dec01:8:00:00   4
2015Dec01:9:00:00   5
2015Dec01:10:00:00  1
2015Dec01:11:00:00  3
2015Dec01:11:30:00  4
```

I wanted to create an ID to identify each loop which always started from status 1 and ended at status 4 (no matter what status between 1 and 4) like this:

```
Time Stamp       Status ID
2015Dec01:1:00:00   1   1
2015Dec01:2:00:00   2   1
2015Dec01:3:00:00   3   1
2015Dec01:4:00:00   4   1
2015Dec01:5:00:00   1   2
2015Dec01:6:00:00   2   2
2015Dec01:7:00:00   2   2
2015Dec01:8:00:00   4   2
2015Dec01:9:00:00   5   .
2015Dec01:10:00:00  1   3
2015Dec01:11:00:00  3   3
2015Dec01:11:30:00  4   3
```

Does anyone can help me out? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your rules (assumed):

1. Increment ID when status=1
2. If status>5 then ID is missing

   ```
   data tmp;
   set have;

   retain ID_TMP 0; *initialize ID;

   if status=1 then ID_TMP + 1;
   if status<5 then ID=ID_TMP;

   DROP ID_TMP;
   run;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We know that a new group has started if `current status is < previous status`. We'll save the previous status using the `lag` function so that we can compare the current status to the previous one.

Create a temporary variable called `count` to count when we increment the ID. Since we are using `if-then` logic, we want to initialize `ID` and `count` with a value of 1 using the `retain` statement.

There are three cases to account for:

1. If the current ID is less than the previous ID, then increment `count` by 1 and set `ID` to be the value of `count`;
2. If the current ID is > 4, set `ID` to missing.
3. Any other time, `ID` will stay the same.

   ```
   data want;
      set log;

      retain count ID 1;

      Prior_Status = lag(Status);

      if(Status < Prior_Status) then do;
          count+1;
          ID = count;
       end;
         else if(Status > 4) then call missing(ID);

      drop count Prior_Status;
   run;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways of doing it.

Method 1:

```
data want;
set have;
if status = 1 then tmp + 1;
if status <= 4 then id = tmp;
else id = .;
run;
```

Method 2:

```
data want;
set have;
if status = 1 then tmp + 1;
id = choosen((status<=4)+1, ., tmp);
run;
```